# CSS Trouble, Why does it move itself?

Tags: javascript, css

I am stuck on the CSS part, am helping a friend to implement one thing on her webpage. Its a dropdown menu and i got everything working the way i want it to. My problem is that it moves itself to the beginning of the row?

http://gazet.se/TestPages/Test.aspx

How do i get it to be centered?

(I have removed the code that has been solved to reduce the size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu has an id called #jsddm

```
#jsddm {
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Remove float left - that is first step. Second thing you should put the menu all in one list with sublevels as nested lists and get rid of img separators - they can be added as background images trough css. I suggest you create a new structure for your menu. Heres a nice article explaining it http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/

Basically all you have to do is add additional `<li>` elements to `#jsdm` and move all menu links inside it.

Comment: Thats better, but how can i add the separator images? and get it centered?

Comment: Also, there are some cracks in the line above?

Comment: You can add them as a background image for list items. #jsdm li {background:url(separator.gif) no-repeat center right;} and for the last item that does not need a separator just add a class on li called "no_separator" or something like that so it resets and looks like .no_separator {background-image:none;} in css.

Comment: Everything works except that it is centered, how can i get it centered again?

Comment: If you have a fixed width on menu you could add a margin:0 auto; if not you have to change display:inline on ul ,li and a but take care to not override second level of the menu (dropdown part).

Comment: #jsddm {display:inline;text-align:center}, #jsddm li {display:inline;float:none;}, #jsddm li a {display:inline} - this will make it centered, BUT then you have to set everything back for second level dropdown (starting from #jsddm li ul).

Answer (score 0):

The menu is floated block element, while the element around it are inline elements, which basicly can't mix. You need to either have all elements in `#header_menu` to also float, or let the menu be inline, too. (However I'm not sure, the latter would work).